# Not giving a project name when creating a react project

Tags: reactjs

While creating a React project, I want to create a react project without creating my-app file instead of npx create-react-app my-app.

I saw examples of such projects, but as a result of my research, I could not find how to do this.

npx create-react-app . i tried but that gave result it wouldn't let me create the project

I want all files to be found directly in the file I created of the react project without my-app file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

it's so simple just write at the end of npx create react app dot it will be like this

```
npx create-react-app .
```